# Ubuntu16.04 : Nginx 1.10 : Nginx serving multiple certificate information. SSL works perfectly on browser, but facing issue with curl. cURL error 51

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, ssl-certificate-errors

I have multiple sites on a ubuntu server(16.04) with nginx/1.10.0 + letsencrypt.

SSL is working fine and perfect by looks in browser. But our developers application which is using a curl request (with SSL) and it facing error as

`Update Failed: Download failed. cURL error 51: SSL: certificate subject name 'domain2.com' does not match target host name 'domain1.com'`

and Upon checking using SSLLABS, it showed A_grade but it is loading multiple certificates (certificate of another domain in same server)

```
Certificate #1: RSA 2048 bits (SHA256withRSA)
```

and

```
Certificate #2: RSA 2048 bits (SHA256withRSA) No SNI
```

and under second certificate, there is following errors.

```
Common names    domain2.com   MISMATCH
Trusted No   NOT TRUSTED
```

Curl error was also saying about the second domain name.

```
cURL error 51: SSL: certificate subject name 'domain2' does not match target host name 'domain1'
```

the domain2 is entirely different site. Don't know how nginx is sending it's information along with domain1.

Also I've tested the same scenario in other servers by creating domain with Letsencrypt SSL and all have same issue. when checking with SSLlabs [ssllabs-checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pkV3.jpg) it is able to get domain2 certificate details along with domain1.Still domain1 Grade is A. also safe in all other checking sites.

and if I'm checking domain2 with SSLlabs it will fetch any other domains certificate which is in same server. (but if there is domains A,B,C,D one of the domains SSL check will fetch only one certificate. that is not issue and all others will have this issue. )

screenshot attached. (a long full page screenshot). I think it will clarify the case :(

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pkV3.jpg)

**I could not use insecure Curl request in application which would neglect this issue and make the curl request success.
If anyone have idea on this please help.
I spent many hours behind this, still....

above issue is for Wordpress plugin and so unable to add specific parameter along with curl. (its from WP core)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The curl version you are using seems to be missing SNI support.

Comment: Try adding the parameter `-H "Host: domain1.com"` to your curl call.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider 
Thank you for the suggestion. couldn't use that solution, all customers using the application are unaware of this. this fails some functionalities in product. Also all issue is regarding the 2nd domain, which not is entirely unrelated one :(

let me try with adding Host

Comment: If you can't change the client you have to change the server. Put the domains on different hosts.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for your help. I upgraded the curl version to  latest one and it resolved the issue with my application. 

Still not aware why the ssllabs are able to fetch other domains certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The curl version in use seems to be missing basic [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) support. SNI is necessary when multiple domains with SSL are hosted on the same IP address.

You have basically three options:

- update curl to a version that supports SNI.
  Support for this was [introduced in version 7.18.1](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_18_1).
- add the host parameter yourself on your clients:
  `-H "Host: domain1.com"`
- Move the domain to use a different IP address. This way no changes on the client are necessary.